# TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I am beginner in solidity and I have to complete this smart contract but my mind is stuck while coding. Please help...

````
```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
    pragma solidity ^0.8.7; 

    contract Farmer {
    uint public f_index = 0;
    struct far{
        uint id;
        string name;
        string phone;
        string gender;
        string dob;
        string bloodgroup;
        address addr;
        Records[] records;
    }
    struct Records{
       string cropName;
       string useableLand;
       string seedCost;
       string seedQuantity;
       string fertilizerCost;
       string fertilizerQuantity;
       string sprayCost;
       string sprayQuantity;
       string harvestCost;
       string laborCost;
    }

    address[] private farmerList;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) isAuth;
    mapping(address => far) farmers;
    mapping(address => bool) isFarmer;

    function addRecord(address _addr, Records memory record) public{
    far memory Far = farmerList[_addr];

    }  
}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`farmerList` is an array of address type. To access an array you need to put in the index of the array which is a number/uint type. So you can not access the farmer array with an address type which is why you are getting the error. Instead of

```
far memory Far = farmerList[_addr];
```

Would be something like:

```
function addRecord(Records memory recordm, uint256 index) public{
    address farmerAddress = farmerList[index];
    far memory Far = farmers[farmerAddress];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Tahlil say "To access an array you need to put in the index". In addition, a few more suggestions to help you get out of the stuck:

Normally mapping is more recommended, however if you need to iterate over elements or return a list then you need to consider using enclosing array, like this:

```
mapping(address => far) farmers;
address[] private farmerList;
```

So, in functions you can access a farmer in mapping by put in address _addr

```
far memory Far = farmers[_addr];
```

And loop throught farmers like this

```
uint length = farmerList.length;
for(uint i; i<length; i++) {
    far memory Far = farmers[farmerList[i]];
    //...
}
```